# Output of PHP as placeholder

Tags: php, html, mysql, iframe

I have a website with an x amount of markers that are stored in mysql database. I want to show the amount of markers (as a figure) showing on the map.

With php I counted the amount of rows in the database, and made an html button that functions as a dropdowntrigger.

Now, I want to have that number as the placeholder on the button.

[image]

Where the `EN` is in the example pic, I want to show the amount of markers. what is the best way to do this??

```
<div class="right">
    <span data-dropdown-id="counter" id="counter" class="button actionButton dropdownTrigger">
        <iframe src="Counter.php"></iframe>
    </span>
</div>
```

Code PHP

```
<?php
require("test.php");


if(!$con)
{
    echo 'Not Connected To Server';
}
if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'test'))
{
    echo 'Database Not Selected';
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM markers";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("<div style='font:25px/25px Arial;color:#73AD21'>$rowcount</div>");
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

UPDATE using echo and iframe:
[update example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5WlK.png)
The text is selectable (cursor changes to 'select') and not clickable (like the dropdowntrigger) and not alined.

Comment: `printf("rowcount");` - You forgot the `$` sign here.

Comment: Sorry, i deleted the div style to make the php script more clear. I edited it back to my initial code :)

Answer (score 0):

just replace `printf("rowcount")` by `echo $rowcount` and I think you shall be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the echo attribut of php and is done. for example if your value is stored in lets say $rowcount.

```
<?php echo $rowcount ?>
```

Printf will output only a formatted string.For example

```
$number = 28;
$str = "India";
printf("There are %u states in %s.",$number,$str);
```

Replace the printf with Echo